# How do I properly read embedded messages on discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically I am trying to scrape content from a discord bot that posts with embedded content. So far I have

```
import discord
import asyncio

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel.id) not in Channels:
        return
    try:
        title=message.embeds[0].author.name
        description=message.embeds[0].description
```

However, the above code never returns anything and gets an index error. So when I tried simply

```
print(message.embeds)
```

It returns an empty list.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is this embed a default embed that discord sends like YouTube?

Comment: Are you using a self-bot? discord.py recently removed support for self bots and anything related to that won't work, otherwise it could be an intent problem

Comment: how does your `Channels` list look like? Are you sure the code comes past the return?